# What does ` 1 stand for in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

While working with LINQ I experienced an exception, it shows `` `1 `` with some expressions.

For example in a stacktrace , I got statement something like this:

```
System.Linq.Table`1.Enumerable();
```

Also in some anonymous statements I came accross the same. One of my juniors asked me about this, but I can't provide him satisfactory answer. So I need to know. What does `` `1 `` stand for?

Comment: \`1 in .Net in general means that's a generic type with 1 type parameter. for example Dictionary\`2 could be a Dictionary<string, int> or any other types, but has 2 type parameters, if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# notates generic types as

```
System.Linq.Table<T>
```

VB notates them as

```
System.Linq.Table(Of T)
```

calling ToString on a type object produces neither C# nor VB syntax; it produces:

```
System.Linq.Table`1
```

Where the 1 indicates the number of type parameters.

In C# a type like:

```
Foo<T>.Bar<U>
```

would produce the string

```
Foo`1+Bar`1
```

Comment: "MSIL notates them as" sounds like it is the MSIL language in which the types are written like that. I doubt it, because if it were like that, how could MSIL actually distinguish between `Foo<T>.Bar<U>` and `Foo.Bar<T, U>`? There may be some default string notation in .NET that outputs generic types like that ... though when testing, it seems that it is *not* `Type.FullName`, which returns *Foo`1+Bar`1* for `Foo<T>.Bar<U>` and *Foo+Bar`2* only for `Foo.Bar<T, U>`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Good point, I had forgotten that Type.Fullname has that behaviour. I'll update the post.